# How to use the root package in an import?

Tags: python

Taking the [Ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible) project as an example, there is, inside the [lib/ansible root directory](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible), many other packages, like this

```
ansible/cli
       /errors
       /...many omitted for brevity
       /utils
       /vars
       __init__.py
```

As an example, from `ansible/utils/vars.py`, the imports start at the root ansible/lib directory, such as

```
   from ansible.errors import AnsibleError
```

and

```
from ansible.errors import AnsibleError
```

rather than

```
from errors import AnsibleError etc.
```

I have a demo project with a directory structure like this

```
beatles/george/harrison.py
       /george/__init__.py
       /john/lennon.py
       /john/__init__.py
       /ringo/starr.py
       /ringo/__init__.py
       /paul/mccartney.py
       /paul/__init__.py
       __init__.py (this __init__.py file is in the beatles dir)
       helpers.py
```

So, using the Ansible example, I tried (in file `john/lennon.py`) to do

from beatles.george.harrison import Guitar

but I get an error `No module named beatles.george.harrison

However, the code works fine if I omit the `beatles` package (the equivalent of ansible in the ansible project)

from george.harrison import Guitar

How come, with my directory structure, I am not able to code the import as

```
from beatles.george.harrison import Guitar
```

from the beatles/john/lennon.py file? If possible, please explain with reference to the ansible project so it's clear why it works in one situation but not the other.

```
>>> from beatles.john.lennon import Guitar Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named beatles.john.lennon 
>>> from john.lennon import Guitar >>> Guitar <class 'john.lennon.Guitar'>
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Ansible is using Python 2.7 and there has been major changes in the import mechanisms in Python 3.

Comment: I'm using 2.7 also

Comment: FWIW, you might want to install [tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-command-unixlinux/) to make it easier to generate a quick tree of files in your package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is that when you install ansible, it puts files into a subdirectory which is accessible from your `sys.path`.  For example, it might go here:

```
/home/leahcim/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

That's just a guess at the location.  `import ansible` and check on `ansible.__file__` for the actual location it ended up in (the exact location is dependent on several things).

Now, if you write a `setup.py` file, you could also get your app visible locally with:

```
python setup.py develop
```

If you don't want to write a working `setup.py` for your app just yet, then you will need to find some other way to make it visible in `sys.path`.

Specifically, the **parent directory of your "beatles" directory** should be contained in `sys.path`.  One easy way to do that is to export it in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, in the other answer where the author didn't install the project and got it to work?

Comment: Because they have mentioned "with my working directory being the one with the beatles folder".  The first entry of `sys.path` is usually the empty string, so that the current directory is searched for import statements.  You should not rely on this detail.

Comment: when you say "working directory" what exactly are you referring to? I copied the beatles folder from the test dir (where it originally resided) and made gave it its own dir in my projects folder (where I keep all my `projects`, python and others), however, the problem remains ,although there's nothing special about my projects folder.

Comment: in my `projects/beatles` folder, if I run `sys.path` in the REPL, it shows the empty string, so shouldn't it work? ```>>> sys.path
['', ```

Comment: ok, thank you, got it to work by adding the working dir to sys.path

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Structure:

```
.
└── beatles
    ├── george
    │   ├── harrison.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── john
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── lennon.py
    ├── paul
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── mccartney.py
    └── ringo
        ├── __init__.py
        └── starr.py
```

and:

```
$ cat beatles/john/lennon.py

from beatles.george.harrison import Guitar

def Guitar(x):
    return "John's guitar"
```

and:

```
$ cat beatles/george/harrison.py

def Guitar(x):
    return "George's guitar"
```

and I can do, **with my working directory being the one with the `beatles` folder**:

```
>>> from beatles.john.lennon import Guitar
>>> Guitar(1)
"John's guitar"
```

Which seems to be exactly your setup as described but does not give an error message when `lennon.py` imports `Guitar` from `harrison.py`.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
```

and

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/py...[etc]
```

so that my working directory is the first item in the path. Have you tried to install your package? Or is it in your working directory?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't see why mine doesn't work. If instead of `from beatles.george.harrison import Guitar`, can you also do `from george.harrison import Guitar`?  Would you expect both to be possible or either/or?  I haven't installed my package. I merely created a project directory and created the subfolders. incidentally, the beatles dir is inside a test dir, but that doesn't make a difference because I copied the beatles folder out of the test dir into its own root.

Comment: also, did you install your package?

Comment: There's no package installation going on here, just running python from the folder where the `beatles` folder is.

Comment: Thank you. Can you also do `from george.harrison import Guitar` from `beatles/john/lennon.py`

Comment: ```>>> from beatles.john.lennon import Guitar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beatles.john.lennon
>>> from john.lennon import Guitar
>>> Guitar
<class 'john.lennon.Guitar'>```

Comment: can I send you a link to a repo and you try my demo project?

Comment: or can you upload your test project?